# Android: Changing ImageView size is not working

Tags: java, android, imageview, size

I am trying to change my ImageView size, but I can't seem to change both - width and height. If I just change one of them, then all works correctly, but when I try to change both, only width is changed.

I have the size in dp: width 22 and height 38, and I convert them to px. Is there another way to do so? I have tried many other ways, but they don't seem to work either.

Could someone tell me, what I should do differently?

Here is my code:

```
public GridLayout gridLayout;
public GridLayout.Spec row = GridLayout.spec(0);
public GridLayout.Spec col = GridLayout.spec(3);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameGrid);
    createBlock();
}

public void createBlock() {
    ImageView block = new ImageView(this);
    block.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);

    if (gridLayout != null) {
        gridLayout.addView(block, new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col));

        int width_in_dp = 22, height_in_dp = 38;
        final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int width_in_px = (int) (width_in_dp * scale + 0.5f);
        int height_in_px = (int) (height_in_dp * scale + 0.5f);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = block.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = width_in_px;
        layoutParams.height = height_in_px;
        block.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried playing with the `block`'s `scaleType`? The default is `fitCenter` but I usually choose `centerCrop` or `fitXY`. [Here's a good webpage that describes the differences.](http://etcodehome.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html)

You can set the `scaleType` through `ImageView`'s [setScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType(android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType)) method.